# What's the CouchDB attachment's md5 digest format?

Tags: couchdb, md5

I'm trying to use the md5 digest of an attachment I put on the CouchDB, but I can't understand what format it uses.

```
{
"_id":"ef467479af422db0c388fa00b3000d40",
"_rev":"3-6d1015e7d25103180817136eefa9f942",
"_attachments":{
    "foo":{
        "content_type":"application/octet-stream",
        "revpos":2,
        "digest":"md5-yDbs1scfYdqqLpxyFb1gFw==",
        "length":1952913,"stub":true }
    }
}
```

That md5 is not hexadecimal but still it is ASCII, how do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part of the digest after the `md5-` prefix looks like it's in Base-64 format.

If parsing in Javascript, the `atob` function can turn it back into binary data.

Assuming the above is correct then the hexadecimal equivalent is:

```
c8 36 ec d6 c7 1f 61 da aa 2e 9c 72 15 bd 60 17
```

Comment: that was it, thank you, now I'm able to use it. I'll accept your answer ASAP

Comment: BTW who's interested in how to obtain bas64 md5 in java: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479067/how-to-decode-with-messagedigest-base64)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to work with the digest format used by couchdb using nodejs you can turn the base64 encoded digest into a "normal" hex string by removing the "md5-" prefix and then do:

```
new Buffer('yDbs1scfYdqqLpxyFb1gFw==', 'base64').toString('hex')
```

To go the other way and create the digest string from a hex value:

```
new Buffer('c836ecd6c71f61daaa2e9c7215bd6017', 'hex').toString('base64')
```